# How to implement custom compar() for scandir()

Tags: c, linux, sorting, alphabetical, scandir

I've been reading the man pages of scandir(), alphasort() and have evidently crammed them all.
But still can't figure out how to implement a custom comparision function.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int mySort(char*, char*);
int (*fnPtr)(char*, char*);

int main(){ 
    struct dirent **entryList;
    fnPtr = &mySort;
    int count = scandir(".",&entryList,NULL,fnptr);
    for(count--;count>=0;count--){
        printf("%s\n",entryList[count]->d_name);
    }
    return 0;
}

int mySort(const void* a, const void* b){
char *aNew, *bNew;
if(a[0] == '.'){
    *aNew = removeDot(a);
}
else{
    aNew = a;
}

if(b[0] == '.'){
    *bNew = removeDot(b);
}
else{
    bNew = b;
}
return alphasort(aNew, bNew);
```

}

Easy to see that am trying to alphabetically sort file names irrespective of hidden and normal files (leading '.').

But a computer will always do what you tell it to but not what you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort routine `mySort` is the issue.  This compare function needs to be of type `int (*)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **)`.  For example:

```
int mySort(const struct dirent **e1, const struct dirent **e2) {
  const char *a = (*e1)->d_name;
  const char *b = (*e2)->d_name;
  return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

---

Recommend changing to

```
int mySort(const struct dirent **e1, const struct dirent **e2);
int (*fnPtr)(const struct dirent **e1, const struct dirent **e2);
```